# javascript: parameterize constructor and arguments

Tags: javascript

I need a function which gets a constructor as first and (a variable number of) additional arguments as following arguments and constructs an object from it.

Is there a javascript way to do this? I have created the following, but I'm by no means a javascript expert and not sure if it is equivalent to what I want.

```
function make_object() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var f = args.shift();
    var obj = Object.create(f.prototype);
    f.apply(obj, args);
    return obj;
}
```

Is this a correct solution? Is there something simpler?

Comment: Have you tested it out? Does it do what you expect it to do/does it do anything unexpected?

Comment: @Mathletics: Yes, I have with a simple testcase and I haven't noticed any difference. I'd like to have equivalence attested more formally, though.

Comment: Well, using `new` would probably be simple enough -- `new Foo('arg')` vs. `make_object(Foo, 'arg')`. Out of curiosity: Why do you need it abstracted like this?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: true, but I think it's cumbersome, ugly and non-idiomatic if you write a statemachine and want essentially `transition(FooState, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Actually I didn't get what your problem is, i mean, what you are trying to accomplish ?

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003: in python-javascript-mix pseudo-code: `function make_object() { return new (argument[0])(*arguments[1:]); }`

Comment: @JoSo Well, `new` is certainly idiomatic JavaScript, though [alternatives are possible](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/118798/). It also seems that you might enjoy some of the upcoming additions to ECMAScript 6 -- `function make(Type, ...args) { return new Type(...args); }` (ref: [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/rest_parameters), [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Spread_operator)).

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes your code should work if you are trying to do what you see below - but as others have commented what is your end goal?  Didn't want to put this code as comment but it's more of a comment than an answer

```
function make_object() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var f = args.shift();
        var obj = Object.create(f.prototype);
        f.apply(obj, args);
        return obj;
    }

    function Person(color, occupation) {
         this.eyes = color
         this.occupation = occupation
    }

    Person.prototype = {
             "homosapien":true
    }

var me = new make_object(Person, 'brown', 'developer');
console.log(me) // logs Object { eyes="brown", occupation="developer", homosapien=true}
```